# How to jump from edit to edit with the keyboard?

Tags: delphi, ide, editor, delphi-10.4-sydney

In a discussion with colleagues, I had been jumping all over a quite large source file, and when closing it the IDE prompted me to save it.
I wasn't aware of essentials edits but wanted to check.

After a lot of undos (Ctrl-Z) I was at the top of the file and when closing it there was no prompt.
It must have been a simple edit in white space or something...

I know I could *also* have looked for colors in the left bar, as in:

[image]

But is there a way to jump from edit to edit with the keyboard?
That would have been the easiest way to check.

I'm using Delphi 10.4 Sydney right now

Comment: Just save the file and do a diff against the version in your repository. If the change is desired, commit it; otherwise, revert to the repository's version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the history button on the bottom right of the editor window.

Then click on differences button at the bottom right side and select two versions you want to compare. Probably the "buffer" which is what you see in the editor and another file you saved before (You have data and time). The number of files in the history can be changed with one of Delphi option.

Then in the bottom part of the window, you see the first difference. Use the Shift+Ctrl+F8 to skip to next difference (Shift+Ctrl+F7 for previous).

See also [DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/History_Manager).

Comment: Thanks. In my specific case, before the save, I don't even need to compare versions. The top most 'Buffer' already contains the changes with the ability to jump with Shift+Ctrl+F8